# Is there a way to open a new tab on a second window in Selenium 4 with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a way to open a new tab on a second window in selenium 4 in Python (And be able to work on that tab). browser.switch_to.new_window('tab') Does not work on a new window opened with browser.switch_to.new_window('window'). It's easily possible to open new tabs on the first window but no matter how I've tried to target a second it doesn't work. I figured out an alternative way to open a new tab with Javascript(execute script) but I have no way to target that tab to open a site on it afterwards. I tried to use the windowHandles method, but that only shows the window handles from the first opened window. Any of the handles from the second opened window don't show.

The code I found to open a new tab on a second window is as follows: browser.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");''')

This opens a new tab, but I have no way to target that tab.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I faced this issue before and you can solve it by creating a new browser instance but as I know controlling multiple tabs is not possible with selenium.

Here is how you open multiple windows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()

#With same chromedriver file
driver1.get('https://youtube.com')
driver2.get('https://google.com')
time.sleep(50)
```

This code will open up 2 separate windows and you will be able to control them both.
I hope this answer will help you!

Comment: This does get the job done, I just wish they'd fix selenium to make it so you could open tabs on new windows easier.

Comment: Yeah, I wished it several times on different projects.  Also, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

For any future visitors, I figured this out myself. It is possible to get the window handle of the new tab opened with Javascript, and then I just used an index of negative 1 on the list of all window handles to select the newly opened tab. So the python would be as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
browser.switch_to.new_window('window')
browser.get('https://google.com')
browser.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");''')
allHandles = browser.window_handles
newTabHandle = allHandles[-1]
browser.switch_to.window(newTabHandle)
browser.get('https://facebook.com')
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Perfect answer, i didn't know either. But isn't it hard to code when you have 5 tabs for example?

Comment: Yes it is, but I made a function called newTab() that has that code in it, then I can just call it if I need another tab. Not so bad then